# Trying to find out in which Clean Architecture's layer does some code logic take place

Tags: flutter, clean-architecture

After learning about Clean Architecture on Flutter thanks to [ResoCoder](https://resocoder.com/2019/08/27/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course-1-explanation-project-structure/)'s wonderful tutorial, I am trying to convert my side project to the Clean Architecture.

However I am facing some difficulties when trying to see in which layer some components of my app go.

My app consists of a Speed Test and UI wise, it displays:

- A "Speed-O-Meter" , like any speed test app with a gauge, some key speed markers and the needle. Please note that the gauge is not linear so computing the needle will require different formulas based on the speed and these markers,
- and a label indicating the bandwidth in a unit set by the user (defaulting to Mbps).

Behind the hood, when the user starts the speed test, the app downloads a file from an URL (but not stored). As the download progress, the bandwidth is computed and the needle's angle calculated, both in real-time.

So how do I go about defining my speed test feature?
So far I have intended to have the following use cases:

- one to download the file, handle the stream and any I/O errors,
- one to compute the bandwidth in a specific unit
- one to calculate the needle's angle based on the computed bandwidth

I like this approach as each concerns are well separated. But should I have gone with one use case? But then it would mean there's only one repo > data source that will perform the download, compute the bandwidth and calculate the angle. Won't it break the Single Responsibility Principle from SOLID?

But If I go with all three use cases, it would mean the following flows:

1. UI > BLoC event > start speed test > download file > file chunk downloaded > BLoC state > UI
2. then UI > BLoC event > compute bandwidth > measured bandwidth > BLoC state > UI
3. then UI > BLoC event > calculate needle angle > new angle > BLoC state > UI

Is that correct, the proper way ?

You can also see than in each flow, the result goes all the way back to the UI (via BLoC states), only for the UI to fire new events to request more stuff. Is that correct as well or should the BLoC do it itself and wrap up the final result (measured bandwidth + needle angle), to the UI? Can the BLoC take such a decision or should be the UI's decision?

Based on that last question, I wanted to say that there is something else I don't understand about the Clean Architecture: who holds the authority in how features behave? Take these settings I have mentioned (+ one):

- the unit in which the bandwidth is displayed
- the formulas to calculate the needle's angle since the gauge isn't linear and
- an update frequency of the speed for a proper UX and usage of the device resources.

Honestly, where do I define and write in code these settings / rules? I would wager inside the use case because [I have read there](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html):

> The software in this layer contains application specific business rules.

But... in regards to the UI, does this mean the use case should tell how the UI should look? Or is it the opposite?
For instance, should it tell the UI how the gauge must be built with all the key speed markers at specific angles? It seems convoluted...

So many questions... I hope you understand and you can help me! Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When deciding about how to structure your business logic into different use cases following SRP is recommended.
This could result in many small use cases. In Clean Architecture it is nowhere stated that use cases cannot be
combined to realize a bigger use case (workflow). So it is not needed to do a round trips to the UI to implement
the full functionality.

Regarding your last question: all your business rules, any formulars and decision making code should be located
in the use case layer. The use case layer would decide about bandwidth unit (maybe based on some configuration),
the presenter would convert it into a string and the view would finally just show that string.

The layout (screen positioning) and style (e.g. colors) of the UI is of course defined in the UI layer.

For a more detailed explanation on use cases in Clean Architecture pls check out my blog post:
http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-UseCases/

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to read and provide a very interesting reply. I have also read your blog with some interest as well. Your idea of having a UseCase (or Interactor in your case) does present a good solution that keeps my views and presenters dumb. So I'll follow that! And will validate your answer accordingly ;-)

Comment: Thx for your feedback! Pls don't forget to accept my answer ;-)